# How to load files for flutter configuration manually?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**Details of my problem:**
I'm trying to run a flutter app through Android Studio. Each time I click Run, gradle needs to load some files from the internet. The problem is that I don't have any access to 'normal' internet. The addresses that it uses to load the files are blocked on the government level. I need to specify proxy to run the app. But I can't find any proxy too because of the same reason.

**Error message:**

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.pom'.
               > Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > Connect to storage.googleapis.com:443 [storage.googleapis.com/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.pom'.
               > Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > Connect to storage.googleapis.com:443 [storage.googleapis.com/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf/x86_debug-1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf/x86_debug-1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.pom'.
               > Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > Connect to storage.googleapis.com:443 [storage.googleapis.com/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: no further information

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 14s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have a vpn program on my phone. I can download the files that it tries to load.

**The question:**
Is there a way to load these files manually or even to avoid using internet connection while running the app?